# Azure Durable function removes files form local storage after it is downloaded

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am struggling a lot with this task. I have to download files from SFTP and then parse them.  I am using Durable functions like this

```
        [FunctionName("MainOrch")]
    public async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
         [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            var filesDownloaded = new List<string>();
            var filesUploaded = new List<string>();
            var files = await context.CallActivityAsync<List<string>>("SFTPGetListOfFiles", null);
            log.LogInformation("!!!!FilesFound*******!!!!!" + files.Count);
            if (files.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var fileName in files)
                {
                    filesDownloaded.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("SFTPDownload", fileName));
                }
      

                var parsingTasks = new List<Task<string>>(filesDownloaded.Count);
                foreach (var downlaoded in filesDownloaded)
                {
                    var parsingTask = context.CallActivityAsync<string>("PBARParsing", downlaoded);
                    parsingTasks.Add(parsingTask);
                }
                await Task.WhenAll(parsingTasks);
            }
            return filesDownloaded;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
```

SFTPGetListOfFiles: This functions connects to SFTP and gets the list of files in a folder and return.

SFTPDownload: This function is suppose to connect to SFTP and download each file in Azure Function's Tempt Storage. and return the download path. (each file is from 10 to 60 MB)

```
        [FunctionName("SFTPDownload")]
    public async Task<string> SFTPDownload([ActivityTrigger] string name, ILogger log, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext context)
    {
        var downloadPath = "";
        try
        {
            using (var session = new Session())
            {
                try
                {
                    session.ExecutablePath = Path.Combine(context.FunctionAppDirectory, "winscp.exe");
                    session.Open(GetOptions(context));
                    log.LogInformation("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Connected For Download!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

                    TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
                    transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;
                    downloadPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), name);
                    log.LogInformation("Downloading " + name);
                    var transferResult = session.GetFiles("/Receive/" + name, downloadPath, false, transferOptions);
                    log.LogInformation("Downloaded " + name);
                    // Throw on any error
                    transferResult.Check();
                    log.LogInformation("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Completed Download !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.LogError(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    session.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError(ex.Message);
            _traceService.TraceException(ex);
        }
        return downloadPath;
    }
```

PBARParsing: function has to get the stream of that file and process it (processing a 60 MB file might take few minutes on Scale up of S2 and Scale out with 10 instances.)

```
        [FunctionName("PBARParsing")]
    public async Task PBARParsing([ActivityTrigger] string pathOfFile,
    ILogger log)
    {

        var theSplit = pathOfFile.Split("\\");
        var name = theSplit[theSplit.Length - 1];
        try
        {
            log.LogInformation("**********Starting" + name);
            Stream stream = File.OpenRead(pathOfFile);
```

i want the download of all files to be completed using SFTPDownload thats why "await" is in a loop. and then i want parsing to run in parallel.

Question 1: Does the code in MainOrch function seems correct for doing these 3 things  1)getting the names of files, 2) downloading them one by one and not starting the parsing function until all files are downloaded. and then 3)parsing the files in parallel. ?

I observed that what i mentioned in Question 1 is working as expected.

Question 2: 30% of the files are parsed and for the 80% i see errors that "Could not find file 'D:\local\Temp\fileName'" is azure function removing the files after i place them ? is there any other approach i can take? If i change the path to "D:\home" i might see "File is being used by another process" error. but i haven't tried it yet. out the 68 files on SFTP weirdly last 20 ran and first 40 files were not found at that path and this is in sequence.

[image]

Question3: I also see this error " Singleton lock renewal failed for blob 'func-eres-integration-dev/host' with error code 409: LeaseIdMismatchWithLeaseOperation. The last successful renewal completed at 2020-08-08T17:57:10.494Z (46005 milliseconds ago) with a duration of 155 milliseconds. The lease period was 15000 milliseconds." does it tells something ? it came just once though.

**update**
after using "D:\home" i am not getting file not found errors

Comment: bulk error was error in  the code i had to increase the timeout of the sql operation. after that things seems to be working.

Comment: got this error again 
Singleton lock renewal failed for blob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others coming across this, the temporary storage is local to an instance of the function app, which will be different when the function scales out.

For such scenarios, `D:\home` is a better alternative as Azure Files is mounted here, which is the same across all instances.

As for the lock renewal error observed here, this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1864) tracks it but [shouldn't cause issues](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1864#issuecomment-555031420) as mentioned. If you do see any issue because of this, it would be best to share details in that issue.